Issue with FluentUI in Blazor WASM: Deserialization Error on Deployed App
I'm experiencing a deserialization error with FluentUI components in my Blazor WASM web app. The error only occurs on the deployed app (using Azure Static Web App), not in the localhost development environment. I'm using the FluentUI framework of Microsoft for UI components, and the error message in the browser console is as follows:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error parsing the event arguments. EventId: '30'.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: DeserializeNoConstructor, JsonConstructorAttribute, Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.AccordionChangeEventArgs Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: DeserializeNoConstructor, JsonConstructorAttribute, Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.AccordionChangeEventArgs
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ReadStack& , Utf8JsonReader& , NotSupportedException )
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_DeserializeNoConstructor(Type , Utf8JsonReader& , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1[[Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.AccordionChangeEventArgs, Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components, Version=4.7.1.24114, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , AccordionChangeEventArgs& )

This error seems to appear when the app tries to render a FluentUI component.
Environment Details

Development Environment: Works fine without any errors.
Production Environment: Throws the deserialization error mentioned above.

How can I resolve the deserialization error related to AccordionChangeEventArgs in my Blazor WASM web app when using FluentUI components? Has anyone faced a similar issue and found a solution or workaround?
I've tried to verify that the same latest version of FluentUI is used in both development and production environments.
GitHub link: https://github.com/hoangvu1420/GemNote_GR.git
The below image is how it looks on the local web:

And this is how it looks on the deployed web:

The GemNote.Web/Pages/Resources.razor is the page that holds the GemNote.Web/Components/NotebookComponents/NotebookComp.razor components.
In each NotebookComp, there are sections GemNote.Web/Components/SectionComponents/SectionComp.razor
I designed the NotebookComp and SectionComp pretty much the same which is a container wrapping a FluentAccordionItem:
<div class="container">
    <FluentAccordionItem ExpandedChanged="OnExpanded">
        <HeadingTemplate>
        </HeadingTemplate>
        <ChildContent>
        </ChildContent>
    </FluentAccordionItem>
</div>

The OnExpanded method of the NotebookComp would call to a service that retrieves the Sections of the Notebook.
I noticed that the OnExpanded of NotebookComp is not called since there was no request sent before the error occurred. Seems like the error occurs as soon as the expand button is clicked.

Can you share your code if possible?

I created a sample Blazor WASM web app with a FluentUI component and successfully deployed it to Azure Static Web App.
I've installed the package - Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components in my project.
To avoid the error you're encountering, make sure that the [JsonConstructor] attribute is applied to the constructor that matches how FluentUI components send JSON data.
I've created a simple project that includes a FluentUI button.
Models/AccordionChangeEventArgs.cs :
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
public class AccordionChangeEventArgs
{
    public AccordionChangeEventArgs()
    {
        SomeProperty = string.Empty; 
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public AccordionChangeEventArgs(string AnyProperty)
    {
        AnyProperty = AnyProperty;
    }

    public string AnyProperty { get; set; }
}

App.razor:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
@using Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components

<FluentButton Primary="true" OnClick="@HandleButtonClick">Click me!</FluentButton>

@code {
    private void HandleButtonClick(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button clicked!");
    }
}

Program.cs:
using FluentUIBlazorApp;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
await builder.Build().RunAsync();

local output:

I've deployed the app to azure static web app via Github actions.

Output after deployment:


Hello, I added the source code and the details of the error in my question, can you check it out? Thank you very much.

@VũHoàng ok I'll try and let you know.
